# Change HTML content and take screenshots in loop (Node.js + Puppeteer / Playwright)

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, puppeteer, playwright

I would like to know the best (the easiest and the most elegant) solution for my problem.

I have data in following format: `Box = {top: val, left: val, width: val, height: val, color: val}`. Their properties are dynamically changed / recalculated in loop. I want to vizualize these structures on webpage, then open webpage by Puppeteer or Playwright, take screenshot and continue in loop. Blocking and execution time would not be a problem.

My first (and current) solution/idea is to:

1. Create new HTTP server
2. Build HTML representation of data in SVG
3. Open webpage in Puppeteer/Playwright
4. Take screenshot
5. Close browser and server
6. Continue in loop with 1.

I am pretty sure there are multiple options how to solve it. Please, give me some advice.

Some other related questions and ideas:

1. My solution doesn't work, because I don't know how to wait for HTTP server to close. It has much overhead, but it isn't problem. Another problem is `EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::8090`, that's because I open new HTTP server in loop and don't wait for previous to close. It is somehow possible to do?
2. One idea is to open HTTP server once and in loop: change HTML content somehow and open the webpage from Puppeteer and take screenshot. Is it possible?
3. Are there some other options? If so, I would be happy to discuss them. Thank you.

**Current solution of creating HTTP server, building HTML and taking screenshot:**

```
function createSvgRepresentation(data) {

  // Create new http server
  const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {

    // Create box representation of webpage data
    var html = buildSvg(req, data);

    // Create http head
    res.writeHead(200, {
      'Content-Type': 'text/html',
      'Content-Length': html.length,
      'Expires': new Date().toUTCString()
    });
    res.end(html);

  }).listen(8090, async () => {

    // Launch Chromium browser
    const browser = await chromium.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    // Set size of viewport
    page.setViewportSize({
      width: 1000,
      height: 600
    });

    await page.goto('http://localhost:8090', {waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded'});

    // Take screenshot of rendered boxes
    await page.screenshot({path: './output/rendered.png', fullPage: true});

    browser.close();
    server.close();

  });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Page.setContent(html)`](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&show=api-pagesetcontenthtml-options) could be an option. You can loop your data over easily (with prepared HTML markup from your `Box` object) and you don't have to deal with the HTTP server anymore.

Example uses Puppeteer:

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')

const box = [
  { top: '0', left: '6rem', width: '5rem', height: '5rem', color: 'red' },
  { top: '3rem', left: '3rem', width: '5rem', height: '5rem', color: 'green' },
  { top: '6rem', left: '0', width: '5rem', height: '5rem', color: 'blue' }
]

const generateMarkup = async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false })
  const page = await browser.newPage()
  await page.setViewport({ width: 1000, height: 600 })

  for (const el of box) {
    const html = `<div style="top:${el.top};left:${el.left};width:${el.width};height:${el.height};color:${el.color};position:absolute;">
        This div has ${el.color} color.
      </div>`

    await page.goto('about:blank')
    await page.setContent(html)
    await page.waitForTimeout(1000)
    await page.screenshot({ path: `./output/rendered-${el.color}.png`, fullPage: true })
  }
  await browser.close()
}
generateMarkup()
```

Comment: I am sorry for late response. That's what I needed. Thank you!